# Can't call some methods of the Camera class (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, methods, camera, fieldofview

It is not possible for me to call the .setFieldOfView method in javafx.scene.camera

I do not know if this is the only one I can't reach, because I seem to be able to use a bunch of other methods like .setLayoutX, .setNearClip etc.

My Camera is a PerspectiveCamera, so I don't know why I can't change the field of view. My workspace uses 10.0.1 if that counts at all.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Your cam variable is a `Camera`, not a `PerspectiveCamera`.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that so thank you very much, I edited my code a bit and now it is working

Comment: No need to add "solved" in a title: instead, post your own answer.

Comment: Yes, I see thank you, however it was not me that answered the question, I was the one that requested a solution